# systemd podman This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies

Tags: containers, centos7, systemd, centos8, podman

I am running container with systemd/pod, when I want to deploy new image tag. stopping service, updating the service file and starting. but container failed to start.

systemd file.

[Unit]
Description=hello_api Podman Container
After=network.target

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /%t/%n-pid /%t/%n-cid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/podman rm hello_api
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run --conmon-pidfile  /%t/%n-pid  --cidfile /%t/%n-cid -d  -h modelenv \
        --name hello_api --rm --ulimit=host -p "8001:8001" -p "8443:8443" 7963-hello_api:7.8
ExecStop=/usr/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/podman rm -f `cat /%t/%n-cid`"
KillMode=none
Type=forking
PIDFile=/%t/%n-pid

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**here is error message.**

```
May 21 10:41:43 webserver systemd[1471]: hello_api.service: Found left-over process 22912 (conmon) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
May 21 10:41:43 webserver systemd[1471]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
May 21 10:41:43 webserver systemd[1471]: hello_api.service: Found left-over process 22922 (node) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
May 21 10:41:43 webserver systemd[1471]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
May 21 10:41:43 webserver systemd[1471]: hello_api.service: Found left-over process 22960 (node) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
May 21 10:41:43 webserver systemd[1471]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
May 21 10:41:44 webserver podman[24565]: 2020-05-21 10:41:44.586396547 -0400 EDT m=+1.090025069 container create 28eaf881f532339766cc96ec27a69d8ad588e07d4bfc70e65e7c54e8a5082933 (image=7963-hello_api:7.8, name=hello_api)
May 21 10:41:45 webserver podman[24565]: Error: error from slirp4netns while setting up port redirection: map[desc:bad request: add_hostfwd: slirp_add_hostfwd failed]
May 21 10:41:45 webserver systemd[1471]: hello_api.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=126
May 21 10:41:45 webserver systemd[1471]: hello_api.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 21 10:41:45 webserver systemd[1471]: Failed to start call_center_hello_api Podman Container.
```

why its giving this error, is there option to cleanly exit the old container?

Answer (score 2):

I think we followed the same tutorial here: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-shareable-systemd-services

> "It’s important to set the kill mode to none. Otherwise, systemd will start competing with Podman to stop and kill the container processes. which can lead to various undesired side effects and invalid states"

I'm not sure if the behavior changed, but I removed the `KillMode=none` causing it to use the default `KillMode=control-group`. I have not had any problems managing the service since. Also, I removed the `/` from some of the commands because it was being duplicated:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f //run/user/1000/registry.service-pid //run/user/1000/registry.service-cid
```

It's now:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/user/1000/registry.service-pid /run/user/1000/registry.service-cid
```

The full service file I use for running a docker registry:

```
[Unit]
Description=Image Registry

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/podman volume create registry
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /%t/%n-pid /%t/%n-cid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run --conmon-pidfile %t/%n-pid --cidfile %t/%n-cid -d -p 5000:5000 -v registry:/var/lib/registry --name registry docker.io/library/registry
ExecStop=/usr/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/podman rm -f `cat %t/%n-cid`"
Type=forking
PIDFile=/%t/%n-pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```